# Show $\lim_{n\to\infty}(Lu_n) = L(\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n)$

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

> Suppose $\{u_n\}$ is a convergent sequence in Hilbert space $H$ and $L$ is a bounded (continuous) linear operator on $H$. Use the definition of convergence to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(Lu_n) = L(\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n)$

Is my proof correct?

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|Lu_n-Lu\|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|L(u_n-u)\|\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}M||u_n-u||=0$

Therefore, $\lim_{n\to\infty}(Lu_n) = L(\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n)$

Solution according to feedback:

the sequence $\{u_n\}$ converges implies
$$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N s.t. ||u-u_n||\leq \frac{\epsilon}{M} \forall n\geq N$$

Now,

$$||Lu_n-Lu||=||L(u_n-u)||\leq M||u_n-u||\leq M\frac{\epsilon}{M}=\epsilon \forall n\geq N$$

Therefore, $\lim_{n\to\infty}(Lu_n) = L(\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n)$

Comment: $L=K$?  You can use $\limsup$ to make this more correct, so that you are not assuming the limit exists, or use directly the $\varepsilon$-$N$ definition of limit.

Comment: I edited my solution. regarding your first comment, I don't see how i am assuming limit exists. I know Lu and Lu_n are defined. then i compute the limit. i mean i am just computing it

Comment: The fact that you write $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|Lu_n-Lu\|$ assumes that this limit exists before you've actually proven that the limit is zero.  The proof would make sense if you instead wrote
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\|Lu_n-Lu\|=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\|L(u_n-u)\|\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}M||u_n-u||=0
$$

Comment: Your new proof is also completely fine.

Comment: Right, or just apply the ["squeeze theorem."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)

Comment: But shouldn't i look at lim inf as well to find $\lim ||Lu_n-Lu||$? Is it because my function is positive and limsup should be greater than liminf then limit exists?

Comment: @user3382078: If $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n$ then automatically $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n\geq 0$, and you can get away without explicit mention of this fact in most contexts.  So if you show that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n\leq 0$, then it follows that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.